# Shortcode does not work, changes html order

Tags: shortcode, post-thumbnails

My shortcode is a mess, he changes the order. This is my code:

```
add_shortcode( 'recent-portfolio', 'brechting_recent_portfolio' );

function brechting_recent_portfolio( $atts ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'numbers' => '5',
    ), $atts ) );

    $rposts = new WP_Query(
        array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => $numbers, 'orderby' => 'date' )
    );

    if ( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
        $html = '<div class="recent-portfolio grid" data-masonry="{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": "img" }">';
        while( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
            $rposts->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $html .= sprintf(
                '<div class="grid-item"><a href="%s" title="">%s</a></div>',
                the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ),
                the_title_attribute(),
                //get_the_title()
                the_post_thumbnail()
            );
        }}
        $html .= '</div>';
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    return $html;

}
```

This is the output:

```
<div class="entry-content2" data-masonry="{ " columnwidth":="" 200,="" "itemselector":="" "img"="" }"="">
    http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/geboortekaart-Bart.pngGeboortekaartje Bart<img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/geboortekaart-Bart.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/geboortekaart-Bart.png 788w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/geboortekaart-Bart-300x171.png 300w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/geboortekaart-Bart-768x439.png 768w" sizes="100vw" width="788" height="450">http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/lejo.pngLejo<img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/lejo.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/lejo.png 788w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/lejo-300x171.png 300w, http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/lejo-768x439.png 768w" sizes="100vw" width="788" height="450">
<div class="recent-portfolio grid" data-masonry="{ " columnwidth":="" 200,="" "itemselector":="" "img"="" }"="">
<div class="grid-item">
<a href="" title=""></a></div><div class="grid-item"><a href="" title=""></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

If I use `get_title()` it works as well, but if I use featured image-based function it's changes the order...

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I have this same problem as well. I'm displaying one random post, and I want to include the thumbnail in the same <a> as the title. My PHP is setup to do this, however the final HTML output is wildly different, as if WordPress is taking my function's output and doing something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail_url()` will echo the URL. You should use functions that have `get_the_...` in the beginning of their names, since functions starting with `the_...` will generally echo the content.

So, your `sprintf` should use [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) like this:

```
        $html .= sprintf(
            '<div class="grid-item"><a href="%s" title="">%s</a></div>',
            get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' ),
            the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ),
            //get_the_title()
            //the_post_thumbnail()
        );
```

However, in this case [`the_title_attribute()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title_attribute) doesn't have a `get_the_...` version as far as I know. But you can disable the echo by passing it as an argument to the function.

Also, use `wp_reset_postdata();` instead of `wp_reset_query()`. The latter should be used when you use `query_posts()` (which you shouldn't use!).

Comment: Does this mean you then have to build up the image tag yourself, ie get the URL, get the classes, get the alt text, etc ?

Comment: @MarsAndBack I'm not sure what do you mean by that. If you want the full HTML output of the image, you can use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` instead.

Comment: Thx, I overlooked that; it's all good.